# parallel for loop with list datatype

Tags: java

```
for (Vertex ex: exitNodes){
              LinkedList<Vertex> longPath = this.getLongestPathBL(task, ex);
              if (longPath != null){
                  flag = true;
                  long temp = Level(longPath);
                  if (temp > maxLevel) {
                      maxLevel = temp;
                  }
              }
          }
```

> I want to execute the above code in parallel, I tried using the code below but the ex is a list not an integer, any idea how I can resolve it?

```
int a= vertexes.size();
IntStream.range(0, a).parallel().forEach(i->{
         // for (Vertex ex: exitNodes){
              LinkedList<Vertex> longPath = this.getLongestPathBL(task, ex);
              if (longPath != null){
                  flag = true;
                  long temp = Level(longPath);
                  if (temp > maxLevel) {
                      maxLevel = temp;
                  }
              }
          });
```

Comment: Looking for `exitNodes.parallelStream()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
vertexes.parallelStream().forEach(i->{
      LinkedList<Vertex> longPath = this.getLongestPathBL(task, ex);
      if (longPath != null){
        flag = true;
        long temp = Level(longPath);
        if (temp > maxLevel) {
          maxLevel = temp;
        }
      }
    });
```

Alternatively you can replace `forEach` loop with map-filter-reduce, e.g.

```
    final Optional<Long> candidateMaxLevel = vertexes.parallelStream()
        .map(ex -> this.getLongestPathBL(task, ex))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(this::Level)
        .reduce(Long::max);
    if (candidateMaxLevel.isPresent()) {
      flag = true;
      maxLevel = Math.max(maxLevel, candidateMaxLevel.get());
    }
```

Remarks:

- As a convention methods should start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `level` instead of `Level`

Comment: now the issue is long maxLevel; flag are declared outside the loop and am getting an error Local variable maxLevel defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final. I declared it as final but still the error is showing

Comment: What I mean is how to modify a local variable i.e flag and maxLevel in the forEach

Comment: I updated my answer on how you can achieve this in a nice way